# Categories not being displayed in tab on manage product screen Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, categories, product

when I click Manage Products > go to a product > Categories tab, the header "Product Categories" is displayed but the Category tree isn't displayed underneath.  This is affecting all products in my store.

The screen looks like this:

[image: category screen]

Nothing is being logged in the error logs so I'm not sure where to start troubleshooting this.  I've found some other solutions online but they don't appear to work.  Any recommendations for troubleshooting or resolving this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Chrome to inspect the column for the Categories tab and found that mod_pagespeed was referenced in place of the Javascript block to display the tree.

I disabled outline_javascript rule in the mod_pagespeed configuration for our virtual host and the tree was displayed again.